# sql complex order by multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `table` category that has an `int` field that can reference the `primary key` in the same table.

like this:

```
ID category         isSubCategoryOf orderingNumber
3  "red t-shirts"         2              2 
1  "clothes"             NULL            1
4  "cars"                NULL            1
6  "Baby toys"            5              1
5  "Toys"                NULL            1
2  "t-shirt"              1              1
```

I want the `table` to be order such that under each category all sub-categories are listed and under that category all of that sub-category.

```
ID category         isSubCategoryOf orderingNumber
1  "clothes"             NULL            1
2  "t-shirt"              1              1
3  "red t-shirts"         2              2 
4  "cars"                NULL            1
5  "Toys"                NULL            1
6  "Baby toys"            5              1
```

Is such a thing possible to do with `SQL` or do I have to order this later by hand?

Comment: Would you please give us an example?

Comment: can you post the actual table data?

Comment: @bmsqldev There is actual table data.

Comment: have you tried order by id  in your query?

Comment: Can your items go more than one level deep? Could "Baby toys" have an additional subcategory for example.

Comment: @TomH yes, in theory it could go infinitely deep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I I understand your needs correctly, you'll need a recursive query to deal with your hierarchical data:

```
WITH recCTE AS
(

    --recursive seed
    SELECT 
        category,
        ID,
        isSubCategoryOf as ParentID,
        orderingNumber,
        CAST(ID as VARCHAR(100)) as Path,
        1 as depth
    FROM table
    WHERE isSubCategoryOf IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    --recursive term
    SELECT
        table.category,
        table.id,
        table.isSubCategoryOf,
        table.orderingNumber,
        recCTE.path + '>' + table.id,
        recCTE.depth + 1
    FROM recCTE
        INNER JOIN table ON
            recCTE.ID = table.isSubCategoryOf
)

SELECT * FROM recCTE ORDER BY path
```

Recursive queries are made up of three parts.

1. The recursive seed, which is the starting point of the recursive look ups. In your case it's any record with a NULL `isSubCategoryOf`. You can think of these as the Root of your hierarchy.
2. The recursive term, which is the part of the recursive CTE that refers back to itself. It iterates until it comes up with no records for each leg of the hierarchy
3. The final Select statement that selects from the recursive CTE.

Here I made a path field that stitches together each ID that is part of the hieararchy. This gives you the field you can sort on to get your hierarchical sort as asked.

It seems like, with your data, your `orderingNumber` is akin to the `depth` field that I added to the recursive CTE above. If that's the case, then you can remove that field from the CTE and save a bit of processing.

Comment: Thanks for yor help. I can't seem to get it to run. I understand your explanation but I can't get the query to run: Incorrect syntax near 'recCTE'.

Comment: Is it SQL server that you are running or a different RDBMS, like MySQL or something? If it's SQL server, what version are you on?

Comment: Actually... if it's SQL server, remove that `RECURSIVE` keyword at the top. Just: `WITH recCTE` I get my syntax messed up between different DBs :/ I've editted the answer to reflect that change.

Comment: Ah ok. Yea... stray parantheses too. Toggling between Teradata and SQL Server has scrambled my brain. Please refer to the updated answer.

Comment: Outer join is not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'recCTE'. Googling says left outer join isn't allowed at all?

Comment: Hey! We're getting somewhere. Just 10 more edits and I think we'll have it. I changed it to an `INNER JOIN` to appease the SQL Server gods.

Comment: yeah, well at least it isn't simple. I still get an error that types don't match: Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Path" of recursive query "recCTE".

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to sotrt and print you can make calculated column

```
select ID, category, isSubCategoryOf, orderingNumber, ID + '_' + isSubCategoryOf as SortOrder
    from table
    order by ID + '_' + isSubCategoryOf
```

Comment: I don't think this will work for OP's needs, although with the small sample records shown, it will. Also, I believe that `order by ID, isSubCategoryOf` would work just as well and wouldn't require the DB to concat fields, saving some cpu.

Comment: yes, you're right. My query returns incorrect result for the question and can just be used as illustration.